# Gnuplot histogram plot style

Tags: gnuplot

I have a data file like this:

```
PS        105  169 169 169   68  0 0 255    105 169 169 169    0  169 169 169    0   169 169 169    0  169 169 169 
GMQ       43    0  255  0    39  0 0 255    40   34 139  34   105 169 169 169    105 169 169 169    0  169 169 169
GL        81    0  255  0    40  0 0 255    105 169 169 169    0  169 169 169    0   169 169 169    0  169 169 169   
CM_{1}    105  169 169 169   47  0 0 255    105 169 169 169    32 169 169 169    105 169 169 169    0  169 169 169
CM_{2}    105  169 169 169   44  0 0 255    105 169 169 169   105 169 169 169    105 169 169 169    0  169 169 169
P         105  169 169 169   105 0 0 255    105 169 169 169    0  169 169 169    0   169 169 169    0  169 169 169
MH        105  169 169 169   69  0 0 255    105 169 169 169    0  169 169 169    0   169 169 169    0  169 169 169
```

in which in the columns 2 6 10 14 18 22 the values to be plotted are reported while in the remaining ones there is the rgb code.

I would like to get a graphic like that,
[image]

while with the attached script the bars are superimposed:
[image]

What should I correct in the script?

This is the Gnuplot script:

```
set term pngcairo enhanced size 2560,2048 font "Arial,50"
set output "Hist.png"
set encoding utf8

unset title

set yrange [0.0:150.]
set style data histogram
set style histogram cluster gap 1
set style fill solid
set boxwidth 1.
set xtics format ""
set ylabel "Training Set size [-]"
set grid ytics lw 2 
rgb(r,g,b) = int(r)*65536 + int(g)*256 + int(b)
unset key

plot "Data.out" u ($0):($2):(0.5):(rgb($3,$4,$5))   :xticlabels(1) w boxes lc rgb variable,\
             "" u ($0):($6):(0.5):(rgb($7,$8,$9))   :xticlabels(1) w boxes lc rgb variable,\
             "" u ($0):($10):(0.5):(rgb($11,$12,$13)):xticlabels(1) w boxes lc rgb variable,\
             "" u ($0):($14):(0.5):(rgb($15,$16,$17)):xticlabels(1) w boxes lc rgb variable,\
             "" u ($0):($18):(0.5):(rgb($19,$20,$21)):xticlabels(1) w boxes lc rgb variable

reset
```

Thanks for the help you can give me.

Best regard.

Comment: Remove the `w boxes` in each plotting line. They override the globally set histogram style

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the gnuplot demo page (http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/histograms.html) clustered histograms should be plotted like this:

```
plot "Data.out" u 2:xtic(1), '' u 6, '' u 10, '' u 14, '' u 18
```

However, I haven't found a way to color the histogram bars individually depending on data from the datafile as you would like to. I got the impression that `... lc rgb var` is not working together with histogram style (but I could be wrong). Maybe someone can tell us.

Therefore, my suggestion for realizing the clustered histogram "manually" with the plotting style `with boxes`. You define a sequence of your columns you want to plot `ColSequence = "2 6 10 14 18"` and a few more functions to shorten the plot command.

**Code:**

```
### clustered histograms realized "manually" with boxes
reset session
unset title
unset key

$Data <<EOD
PS        105  169 169 169   68  0 0 255    105 169 169 169    0  169 169 169    0   169 169 169    0  169 169 169 
GMQ       43    0  255  0    39  0 0 255    40   34 139  34   105 169 169 169    105 169 169 169    0  169 169 169
GL        81    0  255  0    40  0 0 255    105 169 169 169    0  169 169 169    0   169 169 169    0  169 169 169   
CM_{1}    105  169 169 169   47  0 0 255    105 169 169 169    32 169 169 169    105 169 169 169    0  169 169 169
CM_{2}    105  169 169 169   44  0 0 255    105 169 169 169   105 169 169 169    105 169 169 169    0  169 169 169
P         105  169 169 169   105 0 0 255    105 169 169 169    0  169 169 169    0   169 169 169    0  169 169 169
MH        105  169 169 169   69  0 0 255    105 169 169 169    0  169 169 169    0   169 169 169    0  169 169 169
EOD

set ylabel "Training Set size [-]"
set yrange [0.0:150.]
set grid ytics lw 2 
set style fill solid 
set boxwidth 1.0
rgb(r,g,b) = int(r)*65536 + int(g)*256 + int(b)

ColSequence = "2 6 10 14 18"
myBoxWidth = 0.8
Gap = 2
ColCount = int(words(ColSequence))
ColNo(n) = int(word(ColSequence,n))
Color(n) = rgb(column(n+1),column(n+2),column(n+3))
BoxOffset(n) = 1./(ColCount+Gap)*n - 0.5
plot for [i=1:ColCount] $Data u ($0+BoxOffset(i)):(column(ColNo(i))): \
    (1./(ColCount+Gap)*myBoxWidth):(Color(ColNo(i))) w boxes lc rgb var, \
     $Data u 0:(0):xtic(1) w boxes
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your help. The script works and returns the image as I wanted. Best Regard